# How to check Phonegap installed or not by Terminal

Tags: macos, cordova, terminal

i have previously installed in my Mac machine .

Now i want to know where it has been installed  and what is its version ?

Is there any Terminal command available which will help me to solve this ?

Also if i want to delete it completely , is there any command available ?

Answer (score 2):

To check version in xp open your cmd type 'phonegap version'. Your path must be set. Otherwise it will not work.